# Python: Pass variable defined in method of one class in one file to another seperate file

Tags: python, oop, wxpython

I have created a class using wxpython called "WindowClass". It has several methods, including the three below:

```
def onOpenFile(self, event):
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(
        self, message="Choose a file",
        defaultDir=self.currentDirectory,
        defaultFile="*.xls",
        wildcard=wildcard,
        style=wx.OPEN | wx.MULTIPLE | wx.CHANGE_DIR
    )
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        self.path = dlg.GetPath()
        self.pathBox.write(self.path)
    dlg.Destroy()

def onGo(self, event):
    path=self.pathBox.GetValue()
def openExcel(self): 
    rbook=open_workbook(self.path)
```

So basically, there are two buttons. One labeled "Select Input File" and one labeled "GO!". Their functionality is defined by the methods above.

I want this path variable to be available in another file, which will take the value (file path) and feed it to a function which opens the excel file.

I am having problems doing this...

This is the beginning of my code in the other file:

```
app = wx.App()
windowClass(None, title="AskNorbert")
sheet = rbook.sheet_by_index(0)
numrows = (sheet.nrows)
numcols = (sheet.ncols)
leadslist = [[sheet.cell_value(i, j) for j in range(numcols)] for i in  range(numrows)]
wbook = copy(rbook)
w_sheet = wbook.get_sheet(0)
....
app.Mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to reuse `self.path` in another function, right?

First, you need to put this function under "`WindowClass`", then use `self.path` as an input to open excel:

```
...
def openExcel(self):
    your_open_excel_function(self.path)
...
```

Second, to make sure self.path not go away when dlg.Destroy(), you can do deepcopy it:

```
import copy.deepcopy

...
if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        self.path = copy.deepcopy(dlg.GetPath())
        self.pathBox.write(self.path)
    dlg.Destroy()
...
```

That is supposed to work for you.

**UPDATE:**

First, make rbook a attribute of WindowClass:

```
def openExcel(self): 
    self.rbook=open_workbook(self.path)
```

Use rbook attribute of that instance. Like this:

```
...
app = wx.App()
my_class = windowClass(None, title="AskNorbert")
my_class.openExcel()
sheet = my_class.rbook.sheet_by_index(0)
numrows = (sheet.nrows)
...
```

Comment: Good idea, but I am still having issues. I get the error "rbook" is not defined...see my recent edit

Comment: @ohbrobig I think you need to give variable rbook a file object, then use it. Otherwise, rbook will be not defined.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that I added some stuff. See the original post now (my bad).

Comment: fyi, open_workbook is a method defined in the xlrd module, which I have imported.

Comment: @ohbrobig My bad. I forgot to tell you to make rbook an attribute first. Check my update.

Comment: great...now i get this error: AttributeError: 'windowClass' object has no attribute 'rbook'

Comment: @ohbrobig Yes. It's because you didn't call function openExcel(). I don't know where you want to invoke it. If no specific requirement, you can put it before rbook.sheet_by_index(0). Check my update.

Comment: It doesn't quite solve my problem. Basically, the way I want it to work, is that after someone chooses a filepath (once there is actually a string in pathBox) and presses the "GO!" button, it opens the file in excel and starts a bunch of other processes. After making rbook an attribute, as you stated above, I still get an error which says: "AttributeError: 'windowClass' object has no attribute 'path'"

Comment: @ohbrobig I think you have `app.MainLoop()` misplaced. `app.MainLoop()` needs to be called in order for the **Select File** button to set `self.path` and for the **Go** button to set the `rbook` attribute if it is an attribute of `WIndowsClass()`